# How to combine SQL queries into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm not familiar with SQL and don't know how to combine multiple queries into one query. How can I combine these two queries into one so that I can get one result in one table?

The first query is to bring back all distinct document status and other fields:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.DOC_COMP, a.CRFNO, a.DOC_DATE, a.APPID, b.REQID, b.REQDT, (SELECT COUNT(a.DOC_COMP) AS StatusCount FROM PSCRF a) FROM PSCRF a INNER JOIN PSCRFWF b ON b.CRFNO = a.CRFNO
```

The second query is to bring back all distinct department:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.DEPT_CD, 
c.DEPT_NM, 
c.USER_ID 
FROM EFORM.USERPROFILE c
```

These two queries will be join using left join:

```
LEFT JOIN USERPROFILE c ON c.USER_ID = b.REQID
```

Result:

The result from this query is to display count of status by department in crosstab. Example as per below:

```
        Dept1 Dept2 Dept3 
Status1   2     1     4 
Status2   1     2     1 
Status3   2     3     6
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGT6L.png)

Thanks

Comment: show your data...

Comment: @maSTAShuFu You can see the attachment.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your info. I've tried to use SQL fiddle, but got error 'Unable to get host  connection: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information is need to be certain on what you are asking but below is my best guess.

```
SELECT a.DOC_COMP AS Status, c.DEPT_CD AS Department, count(*)
FROM PSCRF a INNER JOIN PSCRFWF b ON b.CRFNO = a.CRFNO
LEFT JOIN USERPROFILE c ON c.USER_ID = b.REQID
GROUP BY a.DOC_COMP, c.DEPT_CD
```

This should get you something like this

```
  Status    Department  Count 
  Status1     Dept1        2
  Status1     Dept2        1
  Status1     Dept3        4
  Status2     Dept1        1
  Status2     Dept2        2
  Status2     Dept3        1
```

ect.

Hope this helps